# Columns name with uppercase PostgreSQL / Doctrine2

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, postgresql-9.6

I've migrate a database from MySql to PostgreSQL. All was ok but I've got columns name like `idEtablissement`, `nomEtablissement` etc...

I'm using Doctrine 2 without Symfony, mapping is done with XML

And when I do a request I've got an error like:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: colomn e0_.idetablissement doesn't exist

Normal because it's named `idEtablissement` in the database

My question is, how can I do with Doctrine or directly in PostgreSQL database to avoid this behavior?

I see that using double quotes around column name is a solution but I don't know how to configure Doctrine to do this (I've already test `setQuoteStrategy(new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AnsiQuoteStrategy())` but it doesn't work)

Comment: It would help if you show us your mapping...

Comment: @Veve it's done ;)

Comment: You'll have to implement you own quoteStrategy for `"`, or much simpler, use only lower case for your columns name.

Comment: @Veve yes, i've rename all my columns to correct it